# Limit submitting many requests Ajax php form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I want to count number of submitted form, and when the count reaches to 3. Ajax should show error message.

I have tried assigning counts to session, and when the count is > 3 i just give wrong query (if there is syntax error in query, ajax displays error)

My ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:'vals/process.php', 
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
        swal("Thank you", "success :)", "success");
    },
    error:function(data){
        swal("Sorry", "error", "error");
    }
});
```

Here is my php

```
$_SESSION['limitRequest'] = 0;

if($_SESSION['limitRequest'] < 3){
    $SQL = "insert into packageorder( id, name) values( '$id', '$name' )";
    $_SESSION['limitRequest']++;
}
else{
    $SQL = "exceed the limit";
}

$Query = mysqli_query($connecDB,$SQL);
```

logically, this method supposed to work I believe, but it is not increasing the value of `$_SESSION['limitRequest']` I think.

How can We fix this? if my method is not usable, how can I restrict the user from submitting so many requests in ajax?

Comment: You're setting the limit to 0, then checking if it's less than 3.  Of course it's less than 3.

Comment: :) Exactly, set your session variable where ver you are starting the session

Comment: oh man. I see now, thanks @durbnpoisn

Comment: this is what happens when you code while you are sleepy.))) you cannot see a small thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `$_SESSION['limitRequest'] = 0` on every execution try this

```
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['limitRequest'] ) {
    $_SESSION['limitRequest'] = 0;
}

if($_SESSION['limitRequest'] < 3){
    $SQL = "insert into packageorder( id, name) values( '$id', '$name' )";
    $_SESSION['limitRequest']++;
} else {
    $SQL = "exceed the limit";
}

$Query = mysqli_query($connecDB,$SQL);
```

It would also be nicer to return a error condittion rather than just something that makes the query fail when the limit is exceeded.

```
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['limitRequest'] ) {
    $_SESSION['limitRequest'] = 0;
}

if($_SESSION['limitRequest'] < 3){
    $SQL = "insert into packageorder( id, name) values( '$id', '$name' )";
    $_SESSION['limitRequest']++;
} else {
    $res = new stdClass();
    $res->error = true;
    $res->errorMsg = "exceed query limit";
    echo json_encode($res);
    exit;
}

$Query = mysqli_query($connecDB,$SQL);

$res = new stdClass();
$res->error = true;    // default status

if ( $Query ) {
    $res->error = false;
    $res->msg = "Update OK";
} else {
    $res->error = true;
    $res->msg = "Query Failed";
}

echo json_encode($res);
exit;
```